# My jquery animation is jumpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, animation

I was trying to make a fade in/fade out animation. I wanted it to wait a few seconds then basically switch between two divs. It works, but it kinda jumps around outside of its container. Heres what it looks like http://programmingbounty.azurewebsites.net/

and here's the relavent section of code:

```
                    <div id = "TopBox" style="height: 350px; position: relative;">
                <div id = "ForReaders" runat="server" style="opacity: 1" >
                    <div id = "Welcome" >
                    Welcome to Programming Bounty, where all your project resources can be easily found and implemented without registration!
                        <br />
                        <br />

                    <ul>
                        <li>Get high quality code and information from our members</li>
                        <li>No signup nessesary unless your making a post</li>
                        <li>Everything is absolutely free!</li>
                    </ul>
                        <br />
                        <a href = "Browse.aspx"> Check it out!</a>
                        </div>

                    <div id = "Catagories" align="center">
                        <h3>What are you searching for?</h3>
                        <div id = "dropdown">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  Width="500px">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select Language</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C#</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C++</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Java</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Objective-C</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Perl</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>PHP</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Python</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Ruby</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Visual Basic</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>HTML/CSS</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <div id = "getfreecodenow">
                                <a href = "Library.aspx"> Get Free Code Now!</a>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id = "ForWriters" runat="server" style="display: none">
                    <div id = "WelcomeProgrammers" >
                    Welcome to Programming Bounty, where you get rewarded for contributions!
                        <br />
                        <br />

                    <ul>
                        <li>Write short code snippets, tutorials or other resources easily</li>
                        <li>People see and use your resources</li>
                        <li>You get paid in either cash or community currency!</li>
                    </ul>
                        <br />
                        <a href = "Library.aspx"> Check it out!</a>
                        </div>

                    <div id = "ProgrammingCatagories" align="center">
                        <h3>What are you searching for?</h3>
                        <div id = "Div3">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="500px">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select Language</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C#</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>C++</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Java</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Objective-C</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Perl</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>PHP</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Python</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Ruby</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Visual Basic</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>HTML/CSS</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />

                            <div id = "GetPaidNow">
                                <a href = "Browse.aspx"> Get Paid Now!</a>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id = "TopCodeWrapper">
                <div id = "TopCodeContainer">
                    <div id = "topcodeheader" dir="ltr">                            

                    <div id = "Popular">
                        <h3>Trending Now</h3>

                    <div id = "tabs" align="left" 
                            style="margin: 0px; ">



<script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function fade() {
        var delay = 5000;
        $(document.getElementById("<%= ForReaders.ClientID%>")).delay(delay).fadeOut("slow");
        $(document.getElementById("<%= ForWriters.ClientID%>")).delay(delay).fadeIn("slow");
        $(document.getElementById("<%= ForWriters.ClientID%>")).delay(delay).fadeOut("slow");
        $(document.getElementById("<%= ForReaders.ClientID%>")).delay(delay).fadeIn("slow");


    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var d = setInterval
    (fade(), 1000);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: The reason can be asynchronous call to all animation.As animation works asynchronously .So every fadein fadeout will call parallely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely misusing `.delay()` and `.setInterval()`.
There is absolutely no need to use .delay() here. It is used to queue timed events on an element. For example `$(element).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn()` will make the element fade out, then after 1 second fade back in. So using it on an idle element has no use at all.

I assume you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EvD66/1/

I'm making the first element fade out and then, using a callback triggered once the animation is over, I make the second one fade in.